# XAMPP - erro com Apache

Tags: php, mysql, aplicação-web, xampp

Eu instalei o `XAMPP` no meu notebook, e ele esta com este erro que eu não sei o que é.

```
10:41:41  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
10:41:41  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:41:41  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:41:41  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:41:41  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:41:41  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:41:41  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:41:41  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Você tinha o mysql instalado previamente?

Comment: Sim, eu havia instalado

Comment: Esta resposta lhe atende?

Answer (score 1):

Este erro é devido ao fato de já ter um `MySql` previamente instalado, este `MySql`que já havia instalado está recebendo requisições na porta 3306 e o `MySql` que você está tentando instalar com o `XAMPP` que vai rodar a porta 3306 que já esta sendo ocupado pela versão que você previamente havia instalado, não tem como ele ocupar uma coisa já ocupada certo? Uma solução seria mudar a porta do `MySql` que você instalou com o `XAMPP` ou desinstala-lo.

> Você tem de mudar a porta em dois arquivos:

1º neste arquivo: `\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini`

2º neste arquivo: `\xampp\php\php.ini`

Comment: é isso mesmo, então eu fui no Serviços do SO e parei o processo e foi normal. Obrigado